# Meaning of "If either of these [inequalities] holds"

Tags: meaning

I have found a statement in a physical paper

"If either of these [inequalities] holds"

and as a non-native speaker I am confused: should it mean

"If both of these [inequalities] holds" or
"If (at least?) one of these [inequalities] holds"?

Is here the key point that there is used "hold**s**" and not "hold" and that is why the second meaning is correct?

Comment: I'd assume your second meaning (at least one).

Comment: 'If either A or B is true, then...' almost always is meant to be equivalent to "If one of the following is the situation: (1) Just A is true / (2) Just B is true / (3) Both A and B are true, then ...".

Comment: The key point here is the word ***either***, not the plurality of the verb ***hold/holds***.. Although we *usually* use the singular verb after ***either***, there are a lot of written instances of [*If either **are** true*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22if+either+are+true%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the inequalities are X and Y, then

"If **either** of these [inequalities] **holds**" = "If **either X OR Y is** true."

"If **both** of these [inequalities] **hold**" = "If **X AND Y are** true."

Either + **is/holds**

Both + **are/hold**